# Magento2 Can not create Invoice Issue

Tags: admin, magento2, invoice

I have updated to latest Magento2 ver. 2.1.0-rc2
Installed form Magento's GIT Branch : 2.1

when I try to create Invoice from admin it throw error :

[2016-06-14 09:53:16] main.CRITICAL: exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'base_grand_total' in 'field list'' in /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:228

Next exception 'Zend_Db_Statement_Exception' with message 'SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'base_grand_total' in 'field list', query was: INSERT INTO `sales_invoice_grid` (`entity_id`, `increment_id`, `state`, `store_id`, `store_name`, `order_id`, `order_increment_id`, `order_created_at`, `customer_name`, `customer_email`, `customer_group_id`, `payment_method`, `store_currency_code`, `order_currency_code`, `base_currency_code`, `global_currency_code`, `billing_name`, `billing_address`, `shipping_address`, `shipping_information`, `subtotal`, `shipping_and_handling`, `base_grand_total`, `grand_total`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) SELECT sales_invoice.entity_id AS `entity_id`, sales_invoice.increment_id AS `increment_id`, sales_invoice.state AS `state`, sales_invoice.store_id AS `store_id`, sales_order.store_name AS `store_name`, sales_invoice.order_id AS `order_id`, sales_order.increment_id AS `order_increment_id`, sales_order.created_at AS `order_created_at`, TRIM(CONCAT_WS(' ', IF(`sales_order`.`customer_firstname` <> '', `sales_order`.`customer_firstname`, NULL), IF(`sales_order`.`customer_lastname` <> '', `sales_order`.`customer_lastname`, NULL))) AS `customer_name`, sales_order.customer_email AS `customer_email`, sales_order.customer_group_id AS `customer_group_id`, sales_order_payment.method AS `payment_method`, sales_invoice.store_currency_code AS `store_currency_code`, sales_invoice.order_currency_code AS `order_currency_code`, sales_invoice.base_currency_code AS `base_currency_code`, sales_invoice.global_currency_code AS `global_currency_code`, TRIM(CONCAT_WS(' ', IF(`sales_billing_address`.`firstname` <> '', `sales_billing_address`.`firstname`, NULL), IF(`sales_billing_address`.`lastname` <> '', `sales_billing_address`.`lastname`, NULL))) AS `billing_name`, TRIM(CONCAT_WS(' ', IF(`sales_billing_address`.`street` <> '', `sales_billing_address`.`street`, NULL), IF(`sales_billing_address`.`city` <> '', `sales_billing_address`.`city`, NULL), IF(`sales_billing_address`.`region` <> '', `sales_billing_address`.`region`, NULL), IF(`sales_billing_address`.`postcode` <> '', `sales_billing_address`.`postcode`, NULL))) AS `billing_address`, TRIM(CONCAT_WS(' ', IF(`sales_shipping_address`.`street` <> '', `sales_shipping_address`.`street`, NULL), IF(`sales_shipping_address`.`city` <> '', `sales_shipping_address`.`city`, NULL), IF(`sales_shipping_address`.`region` <> '', `sales_shipping_address`.`region`, NULL), IF(`sales_shipping_address`.`postcode` <> '', `sales_shipping_address`.`postcode`, NULL))) AS `shipping_address`, sales_order.shipping_description AS `shipping_information`, sales_order.base_subtotal AS `subtotal`, sales_order.base_shipping_amount AS `shipping_and_handling`, sales_invoice.base_grand_total AS `base_grand_total`, sales_invoice.grand_total AS `grand_total`, sales_invoice.created_at AS `created_at`, sales_invoice.updated_at AS `updated_at` FROM `sales_invoice`
 LEFT JOIN `sales_order` ON sales_invoice.order_id = sales_order.entity_id
 LEFT JOIN `sales_order_address` AS `sales_shipping_address` ON sales_invoice.shipping_address_id = sales_shipping_address.entity_id
 LEFT JOIN `sales_order_address` AS `sales_billing_address` ON sales_invoice.billing_address_id = sales_billing_address.entity_id
 LEFT JOIN `sales_order_payment` ON sales_invoice.order_id = sales_order_payment.parent_id WHERE (sales_invoice.entity_id = '8') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `entity_id` = VALUES(`entity_id`), `increment_id` = VALUES(`increment_id`), `state` = VALUES(`state`), `store_id` = VALUES(`store_id`), `store_name` = VALUES(`store_name`), `order_id` = VALUES(`order_id`), `order_increment_id` = VALUES(`order_increment_id`), `order_created_at` = VALUES(`order_created_at`), `customer_name` = VALUES(`customer_name`), `customer_email` = VALUES(`customer_email`), `customer_group_id` = VALUES(`customer_group_id`), `payment_method` = VALUES(`payment_method`), `store_currency_code` = VALUES(`store_currency_code`), `order_currency_code` = VALUES(`order_currency_code`), `base_currency_code` = VALUES(`base_currency_code`), `global_currency_code` = VALUES(`global_currency_code`), `billing_name` = VALUES(`billing_name`), `billing_address` = VALUES(`billing_address`), `shipping_address` = VALUES(`shipping_address`), `shipping_information` = VALUES(`shipping_information`), `subtotal` = VALUES(`subtotal`), `shipping_and_handling` = VALUES(`shipping_and_handling`), `base_grand_total` = VALUES(`base_grand_total`), `grand_total` = VALUES(`grand_total`), `created_at` = VALUES(`created_at`), `updated_at` = VALUES(`updated_at`)' in /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:235

Comment: after running this SQL : **ALTER TABLE  `sales_invoice_grid` ADD  `base_grand_total` DECIMAL( 12, 4 ) NOT NULL AFTER  `grand_total` ;**

it works but is this correct way to resolve this ?

Comment: I had the same issue after an upgrade from 2.0.1 today, this resolved it for me too.  However, it was when placing an order, not when manually creating an invoice.  After the above SQL command orders could be places but I have serious doubts about the integrity of the db now.

Answer (score 1):

This is a magento core issue (MAGETWO-54787 ticket) that was fixed after 2.1.0 release. See https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/5546 and https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/4785